# In which quadrant of the circle does the angle of $90^\circ$ lie?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, reference-request

*By definition* and *with an authoritative reference*, in which quadrant or quadrants does $90^\circ$ lie?

([There](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrant_%28plane_geometry%29) [are](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Quadrant.html) [non](http://planetmath.org/quadrant)-[authoritative](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080212133729AAB5qmK) [references](https://math.la.asu.edu/~surgent/mat170/trig_notes.pdf) which answer the question, and a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090843/which-quadrant-is-the-first-quadrant) which touches on the topic, but I suppose I am asking if the the signs must be *strictly* positive/negative - with robust source(s) to back up the statement).

Comment: A completely analogous question seems, to me, to be "Is $0$ on the left or right half of the numberline?"

Comment: I doubt that there is an authoritative reference. In any context in which it matters an author should make clear what convention he or she is following.

Comment: @EthanBolker, if a statement by an authoritative source says something to that effect, then it is a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: Perhaps someone here will answer with a source you accept as authoritative. Perhaps someone else will find an equally authoritative source with a different opinion. I think it's that kind of question.

Comment: @EthanBolker, then the answer would be: "There is no universally accepted definition. Author A in Book X defines ... whereas Author B in Book Y defines ..." 

The fact there is not a universal accepted definition is an answer in itself.

Comment: There is obviously not an universally accepted definition.

Comment: Directed angles in standard position (vertex at the origin with initial side on the positive $x$-axis) whose terminal side lies on one of the coordinates axes are called [quadrantal angles](http://www.mathopenref.com/trigquadrantal.html).  They do not lie in a quadrant since their terminal sides do not lie in a quadrant.

Comment: If you slice a cake into two pieces, which piece of cake has been cut?

Comment: The cosine of an angle in Quadrant 1 is positive, but the cosine of an angle in Quadrant 2 is negative. Since cos(90) = 0, it's clearly not in Quadrant 2. But since most mathematicians do not include 0 in the set of positive numbers, then it's not in Quadrant 1, either. As N. F. Taussig suggested, it does not lie in any quadrant.